# NSIS: using environment variable at compile time?

Tags: environment-variables, nsis

If I'm not mistaken, all discussion about environment variables (EVs) in NSIS [docs](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter3.html#3.1.3) (eg `ReadEnvStr`), deal with EVs in the target computer: all happens at **install** time.

I wonder if there is any support for accesing EVs on the developer (build) machine, at **compile** time. Specifically, suppose I have

```
!define SRCDIR "C:\progs\version1\src"

...
File /r "${SRCDIR}\*.*"
```

and I'd rather want to write

```
!define SRCDIR "%{PROG_DIR}\src"
```

(or something similar), where `PROG_DIR` is an environment variable.
Can this be done?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
!echo "$%temp%"
```

I'm pretty sure this is documented somewhere.

Comment: Well, it was indeed simple, but I didn't find it documented anywhere (nor even a mention to this distinction between env variables in target computer vs build computer). It works, thanks.

Comment: It is documented under "5.3 Read environment variables"